# Can't access whole model functionality after loading pb file in TF2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

After I trained my model in custom training using TF2 with tapes, I saved it using tensorflow's basic **save_model** function in **.pb** format. I'm regretting now that I didn't saved as h5 file.

I used keras functional layers within my architecture and I could modify them and use .summary() as usual.

Actually my model has been saved properly with it's layers and weights and I also can access them using **imported_model.layers**. Even inferring from model isn't a problem since I can `f = imported.signatures["serving_default"]` and `f(input_1=x, input_2=y, input_3=z)`.

However when I try to edit the model I can't really access it for example summary() function returns empty. I receive a error like

***ValueError: You tried to call `count_params` on input_1, but the layer isn't built. You can build it manually via: `input_1.build(batch_input_shape)`.***

Should I really rerun my model or is there any way that I can edit my architecture? For example I have 3 inputs and one of them connected to a non-trainable Embedding layer and I want to examine it's output and then provide new embedding inputs to the model.

Comment: Can you provide the reproducible code so that we can understand the issue better and we can help you. Thanks!